# Bind exception while running FlumeEventCount

Tags: streaming, apache-spark

Iam trying out spark streaming examples with apache flume.
For installation, I have  just unzipped spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop1.tar.gz and  apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz for running spark streaming examples.Is this the correct way or else Is there any other way, then just let me know.

With the above mentioned steps.. I have tried executing the examples, it throws an bind exception. Can someone help me with this issue ?
My flume is running properly it is able to push the data on relevant port...

The error Iam facing is mentioned below..

```
 14/11/07 23:19:23 ERROR scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0:                          Error starting receiver 0 - org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: 
Failed to bind to: /172.29.17.178:65001
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.java:106)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
 Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)


Even after killing the specific port still facing with the similar issue..
Can someone help me to resolve this issue..
```

Answer (score 0):

That port is already in use.
From your log:
"Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use"
Use another one.